# how can get direct link from youtube video with youtube api v3

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I have seen multiple sites that use **direct link** from youtube.

For example, for this youtube link :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yY6ex5Dqkks

the direct link for quality 720p is :
http://r12---sn-n4v7kne7.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?sparams=dur,expire,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,nh,pl,ratebypass,source,upn&key=cms1&mime=video%2Fmp4&fexp=9416126%2C9416891%2C9420452%2C9422596%2C9423662%2C9427902%2C9428399&expire=1459599509&ipbits=0&upn=99USaJ1LnkA&dur=30.093&pl=48&lmt=1459568922521937&signature=63FE6D047E895678BAD75266A901C5ABA672A189.0ABBCAA69A9C69003ED38AC11CC08BBF237BB1B3&itag=22&source=youtube&ip=2604:a880:1:20::1ff:1&ratebypass=yes&id=o-AJMIxtvMFBps0IkCDE5t76_cGObBwaTk_xoexDWKt2c0&sver=3&cms_redirect=yes&mm=31&mn=sn-n4v7kne7&ms=au&mt=1459577754&mv=m&nh=IgpwcjAxLnBhbzAzKgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&utmg=ytap1&title=New%20TV%20Ad:%20%22Nose%22

How can I get this direct link with youtube api v3 or any other.

Answer (score 1):

use https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/ with `-g`.  here are some more characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get direct link using youtube api, because it is against their [terms](https://www.youtube.com/t/terms).
So they won't allow you to get download link using their api.

> Content is provided to you AS IS. You may access Content for your information and personal use solely as intended through the provided functionality of the Service and as permitted under these Terms of Service. You shall not download any Content unless you see a “download” or similar link displayed by YouTube on the Service for that Content. You shall not copy, reproduce, make available online or electronically transmit, publish, adapt, distribute, transmit, broadcast, display, sell, license, or otherwise exploit any Content for any other purposes without the prior written consent of YouTube or the respective licensors of the Content. YouTube and its licensors reserve all rights not expressly granted in and to the Service and the Content.

Comment: they must be using some third party api, there are some online apis or libraries which will help you generate direct links but not by google api.

Comment: That site is breaking the YouTube TOS.

Comment: can you any body help me for this problem?